# Is there a list of hiking shelters in Quebec?

Tags: online-resources, canada, accommodation, hiking, quebec

I am looking for possible multi-days hikes in Quebec (Canada) (and beyond but that would be too broad). I keep discovering new places to stay overnight, as there does not seem to be a central list of shelters of the whole province.

By shelter I mean a place shared by multiple people (bookable as a single hiker) and that is specifically made for hikers (or back-country skiers). I.e. hostels, inns and hotels do not qualify.

I would like to know if some website gathers information about all community shelters of Quebec.

In particular, I am thinking of maybe going along the [TransCanada trail](http://tctrail.ca/explore-the-trail/) (but it is not complete so I am not sure there are actually shelters along the way).

Comment: Do you have a itinerary of places you want to go?

Comment: @Amine I updated the post. But I am not only searching along the TransCanada trail

Comment: See also [Outdoors.SE].

Comment: Have a look at this site: [Sepaq](http://www.sepaq.com/hebergement/)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I could not find a centralised list of all community shelters in Quebec. However, I could list some organisations that manage shelters and list some of those along [a small portion of the Trans-Canada trail (Sentier National in Quebec)](http://www.parcsregionaux.org/wp-content/uploads/2013/06/TABLEAU-DES-SENTIERS.pdf), from Mont-Tremblant to the reserve Mastigouche. I list them in the order West-East.

For each shelter, I try to list the following:

| [name] | [capacity] | [price per night per person] | [location(optional)] | [access from previous shelter] | [opening period] |

### Sepaq

The [Sepaq](http://www.sepaq.com/) manages many provincial parks (called national parks) and the Trans-Canada trail crosses them in multiple places. The Sepaq operates shelters all over Quebec in its parks of Fjord-du-Saguenay, Gaspésie, Grands-Jardins, Mont-Mégantic, Mont-Orford, Mont-Tremblant, Monts-Valin and Yamaska.

#### in Mont-Tremblant national park

- | Lac-Ernie | 18 people | ~25$ | access from Lac Monroe Park center : ~13km | open May-March |
- | Lac-des-Sables | 18 people | ~25$ | access from Lac-Ernie : 9.5km | open May-March |
- | Le Lariou | 2 people | ~25$ | access from Lac-des-Sables : ~10km | open May-March |
- | Le Geai-Bleu | 4 people | ~25$ | access from Le Lariou : ~5km, from La Pimbinia Park - entrance : few km | open May-March |

This is an alternative way to link Mont-Tremblant and St-Donnat, the Trans-Canada trail follows the Intercentre trail (see below).

### Intercentre

The ["Intercentre" trail](http://www.intercentre.qc.ca/) links Lac-Laurier and St-Donat, and is a part of the trans-Canada trail.

- | [Le Nordet](http://www.intercentre.qc.ca/index.php?idPage=refuge&p=2) | 8 people | 22$ | N 46° 14' 10", W 74° 23' 55.2" | [access from parking on the chemin du Nordet : 6.5km](http://www.intercentre.qc.ca/index.php?idPage=sentier&p=7) (north of Lac-Supérieur) | open year-round |
- | [Le Lac de l'Appel](http://www.intercentre.qc.ca/index.php?idPage=refuge&p=2) | 8 people | 22$ | N 46° 15' 57.2", W 74° 21' 14.8" | [access from Le Nordet: 6.7km, to chemin Regimbald : ~15km](http://www.intercentre.qc.ca/index.php?idPage=sentier&p=7) - open year-round |

From the chemin Regimbald, it is possible to reach highway 329 and from there follow the chemin Wall to continue on the Mont-Ouareau trail.

### FQMarche (Quebec Federation of Hiking)

The [FQMarche](http://www.fqmarche.qc.ca) manages two shelters, both along the Trans-Canada trail, one in the area of Mont-Ouareau:

| [Paul Perreault](http://www.fqmarche.qc.ca/index1.asp?id=729) | 12 people | 10-15$ | near Lac Lemieux | [hwy 329 : 4-6km, hwy 125 : 8.5km](http://www.parcsregionaux.org/wp-content/uploads/2013/06/8x14_sn_mont-ouareau_2_v21.pdf) | open year-round |

The Trans-Canada trail is discontinued along the highway 125, it starts farther on the Massif trail in the regional park of the Ouareau forest.

### Parc Régional de la Forêt Ouareau

I could not find a mention of when the shelters are open, but it seems they are operated in summer and winter. They all appear on the [map of the Massif trail](http://www.parcsregionaux.org/wp-content/uploads/2013/06/carte_fora_t_ouareau1.pdf)

- | Pelletier | 8 people | 30,25$ | near Lac à Pelletier - ~3km from hwy 125, near Notre-Dame de la Merci |
- | Prud'homme | 8 people | 30,25$ | 2.5km from Pelletier shelter |
- | La Loutre | 2 people | 30,25$ | 2km from trans-Canada trail |
- | Corbeau | 6 people | 30,25$ | 2km from trans-Canada trail |
- | Toussaint | 8 people | 30,25$ | 16.5km from Prud'homme shelter |
- | des Capucines | 6 people | 30,25$ | 4km from Toussaint shelter |

Then the trail continues without any shelter (but some lean-to) on the [Contreforts](http://www.parcsregionaux.org/wp-content/uploads/2013/06/8x14_sn_contreforts_4_nov_20121.pdf) and the Swaggin trails.

### Parcs Régionaux Matawinie - Sentier National

I could not find a mention of when the shelters are open, but it seems they are operated in summer and winter.

- | Swaggin | 20 people | 25$ | the previous shelter on the trans-Canada trail is on the Massif trail, 38km away (refuge des Capucines) |
- | Lavigne | 8 people | 25$ | [6.5km from Swaggin shelter on La Boule trail](http://www.parcsregionaux.org/wp-content/uploads/2013/06/8x14_sn_swaggin_boule_5_sept_201211.pdf) |
- | Lac Boule | 8 people | 25$ | near Lac de la Boule - [10km from Lavigne shelter on La Boule  trail](http://www.parcsregionaux.org/wp-content/uploads/2013/06/8x14_sn_swaggin_boule_5_sept_201211.pdf) |
- | Bazinet | 8 people | 25$ | near Lac des Iles - [~11km from Lac Boule shelter, on Perces-Brumes trail](http://www.parcsregionaux.org/wp-content/uploads/2013/06/8x14_sn_perces_brumes_6_nov_20122.pdf) |

The trans-Canada trail continues on several successive trails (Ours, Matawinie, Nymphes, Mistikush) without any appareent shelter on the way (see the [Cartes tab of Matawinie page for the trans-Canada trail for maps of these trails](http://www.parcsregionaux.org/parcs-regionaux/parcs/sentier-national/)).

### FQMarche (Quebec Federation of Hiking)

A second shelter managed by the FQMarche is at the end of Mistikush trail:

| [Grand-Masti](http://www.fqmarche.qc.ca/index1.asp?id=730) | 6 people | 10-15$ | near Morin Creek, [parking in ZEC des Nymphes : ~14km through Nymphes and Mistikush trails](http://www.fqmarche.qc.ca/uploads/refuge_grandmasticarte.pdf), [~15km along Cheriore trail to a parking near Petit William cabin (not bookable for only one person)](http://www.fqmarche.qc.ca/uploads/SNQ-Cheriore_C.jpg) | open in summer (May 17 to Sep 1st) |

Then the Trans-Canada trail arrives in the [reserve Mastigouche](http://www.sepaq.com/resources/docs/rf/mas/mas_carte_generale.pdf), with no shelter open to single-person reservation.

This list of shelters along the Trans-Canada trail in Quebec is definitely incomplete as the trail is particularly long (1100km) but I hope to enrich it with time.

### SIA-IAT (International Appalachian Trail)

The [International Appalachian Trail](http://www.sia-iat.com/en/accueil.html) group manages a set of shelters, not along the trans-Canada trail but still worth noting. They publish [a list of their shelters](http://www.sia-iat.com/en/hebergement_sites_SIA_Qc.html). I do not list them as they are not along the Trans-Canada trail but along the Quebec section of the International Appalachian Trail.

Answer (score 5):

The Fédération québécoise de la marche, a non-profit that promotes hiking in Quebec, lists shelters on its site and Facebook page (http://www.fqmarche.qc.ca/ and https://www.facebook.com/pages/F%C3%A9d%C3%A9ration-qu%C3%A9b%C3%A9coise-de-la-marche/138582999548977).